# vb.net having to click button twice

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a data entry form

when you click the ok-button it should add the form data into the database and close the form (dialog)

unfortunately I often encounter an issue where I have to click the button twice for it to save the data entry and close the form.

It's almost as if the first click only results in me a "Enter" event and not a click event

The code I use to open the dialog

```
Private Sub addSavingButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addSavingButton.Click
    Dim frm As New savingForm
    frm.initiative_Id = initiative_Id
    If frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.SavingRegistrationListViewTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BA_ACO_V2DataSet.savingRegistrationListView)
        Me.SavingRegistrationListViewBindingSource.Filter = "initiative_Id = " & initiative_Id
    End If
End Sub
```

The code on my OK-button

```
Private Sub savingOkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles savingOkButton.Click
    Dim SQLText As String
    Dim errorForm As Integer = 0
    SQLText = "EXEC BA_ACO_V2.dbo.insertNewInitiativeSaving "
    SQLText = SQLText & "@initiative_Id = " & initiative_Id
    SQLText = SQLText & ", @created_By_Init = '" & Environment.UserName & "'"

    If savingPeriodComboBox.SelectedValue = 0 Then
        errorForm = 1
    Else
        SQLText = SQLText & ", @savingsPeriod_Id = " & savingPeriodComboBox.SelectedValue
    End If
    If savingRegTypeComboBox.SelectedValue = 0 Then
        errorForm = 1
    Else
        SQLText = SQLText & ", @savingsRegType_Id = " & savingRegTypeComboBox.SelectedValue
    End If

    SQLText = SQLText & ", @savingInDKK = '" & savingInDkkNumericUpDown.Value & "'"
    SQLText = SQLText & ", @savingInPct = '" & savingInPctNumericUpDown.Value & "'"

    If errorForm = 1 Then
        MsgBox("Please fill out entire form")
    Else
        Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ACO_V2._1.My.MySettings.BA_ACO_V2ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        DBConnection.Open()
        Dim DBCommand As New SqlCommand(SQLText, DBConnection)
        Dim DBDatareader As SqlDataReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim DBResult As String = ""
        While DBDatareader.Read()
            DBResult = DBDatareader.GetValue(0)
        End While
        DBConnection.Close()

        If DBResult = "Row inserted OK" Then
            savingOkButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        Else
            savingOkButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you debug? Does the first click even register the code-behind event and execute any logic?

Comment: It does register and it writes data to the database, I have even gone so far as to put a MsgBox right before setting my DialogResult = OK and it appears on the first click and the form closes on the second click

Comment: Replaced "savingOkButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK" with "Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK" this did the trick

Comment: Good, as I was just getting ready to ask you to post the HTML to get a better look.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm had a brain wave

quick fix

```
Private Sub savingOkButton_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles savingOkButton.Enter
    savingOkButton.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

Comment: Enter will fire if you _Tab_ into the button.  No click necessary. This will be a very bad UI experience.

Comment: Hmm in that case I still need to solve my issue another way.